# Making RB movement smoother/curvy. C#. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am trying to make my rb movement more smooth/ curvy, rite now it only moves with rough edges when changing move direction.

Current movement
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H82d.png)

Desired movement
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqqeK.png)

The code is below
https://repl.it/@RicardsQuagmier/AcclaimedTightCosmos#main.cs

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your movement is entirely input based. Whenever you are pressing a key, it moves as long as you're pressing it. In that case, the player is entirely in control of the movement which is why it would be so rigid. If you smooth the movement, input might feel very slippery. If you want to do it anyway, you'd want to gradually change the velocity instead of instantly. So when setting velocity, you'd want to do it something like:

```
var delta = 0.2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
velocityChange = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb.velocity, desiredVelocity - velocity, delta);
```

You can set the 0.2 in delta to whatever you want, adjust it to your liking. The higher it is, the quicker the velocity would catch up to input. Like I said this may make things feel unresponsive or slippery though.